# Issue in loading local html file in Android WebView on Android 5.0

Tags: android, html, webview

Today, I've noticed a strange issue when loading local **.html** files (in assets Android's project folder). The first page, loaded in this way, works:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/login.html");
```

So I can see login.html.
On that page, there are some links. When I try to open one of these links, I've error message saying: "file not existing or is not possible to open it".
The strange thing is that it's happening only on **Android 5.0**.
On **Android 4.3** it was working well.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please provide some sample HTML that exhibits this behavior. Also, are you using a `WebViewClient` to control what happens when users click links, or are you accepting the default, launch-the-user's-default-browser behavior?

Comment: I'm not using WebViewClient